# Fourier Transform of $(1/9)^t$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am doing a Fourier Transform for the function $f(t)=(1/9)^t\cdot \text{UnitStep}(t+9)$.
   $$\int_{-9}^{+\infty} (1/9)^t*e^{-j\Omega t}\, dt$$
but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that 
$$\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^t = e^{t\cdot\ln\left(\frac19\right)}=e^{-t\ln 9}$$ helps you transform the expression into $$\int_{-9}^{+\infty} e^{-t(\ln 9+j\Omega)}dt$$ which should help you.